# How to force iOS to install iPhone Apps?

Tags: ios

The iPad let me install iPhone Apps, which is good. However, if an App has an iPad and an iPhone version, iOS forces you to install the iPad version (the iPhone option is not available).

I want to install Google Chrome for the iPhone on my iPad, is that possible?

Comment: You could try using the iPhone Configuration Utility: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465 First, download the iPhone version of Chrome using iTunes. Once downloaded, right click on the app and choose "show in Finder." Connect your iPad. Launch the iCU, select the iPad and then click on the Applications. Now drag the IPA over to the iCU window and see if it will install the app. If it doesn't work, you are probably out of luck. Apple locks things down pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

If an app is "Universal," then it will contain code for both the iPhone and the iPad.  When launched, iOS detects this, and the app will automatically display a UI that is appropriate for that device.

The only way to change this behavior would be to modify the core system behavior, which could be done only on a jailbroken phone.

The exception is found in applications where the developer has two completely separate applications for iPhone and iPad.  In that case, you could force the iPhone app to be installed on an iPad.